# Where is the NodeJS idle loop?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using ExpressJS and Socket.IO I have an HTML scene where multiple users can connect to NodeJS. I am about to do some animation that has to sync to all clients.

In the client, I know animation can be achieved by setInterval() (not time-ideal) then socket.emit() to NodeJS. But is there an Idle loop in NodeJS that can be used for master-controlling animations and io.sockets.emit() to update everyone about everyone?

EDIT: I want to do general "animation" of values in node.js e.g. pseudocode:

```
process.idle(function() {

     // ...
     itempos.x += (itempos.dest - itempos.x) / 20; // easing
     itempos.y += (itempos.dest - itempos.y) / 20; // easing

     io.sockets.broadcast('update', itempos);
     // ...
});
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. For animations I suggest looking into `requestAnimationFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: node has setInterval as well..

Comment: @AJcodez I need an idle loop so as to process data as fast as possible.

Comment: Note: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2543

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a server-side framework it will rarely idle (CPU or I/O). Besides idleloop is more suited for DOM requirements. But in node.js you have the following functions:

1. [process.nextTick](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) : Execute callback after current event queue finishes i.e. at the beginning of next event loop. It does not allow I/O execution until [`maxTickDepth`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_maxtickdepth) `nextTick` calls are executed. If used too much it can prevent I/O from occurring.
2. [setImmediate](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) : Execute callback after I/O callbacks in current event loop are finished. Allows I/O to happen between multiple `setImmediate` calls.

Given what you want `setImmediate` is more suited for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Timers docs: http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

> All of the timer functions are globals.
>
> `setInterval(callback, delay, [arg], [...])`
>
> To schedule the repeated execution of callback every delay milliseconds. Returns a intervalId for possible use with clearInterval(). Optionally you can also pass arguments to the callback.

For synchronized client animation it may make sense to do sequences in chunks at a slower rate than trying to squeeze as many websocket emissions into the animation duration. Human eyes are much slower than websockets in my experience.

There's tons of client frameworks that will do the easing for you, not a server concern.

(All of this oblivious to your use case, of course!)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am just exploring NodeJS at the moment so I am not looking to do anything in particular. The easing example was just made up. From comments so far, seems like there is no traditional idle loop then?

Comment: To my knowledge idle loops are for background tasks. With event-driven architectures, basically everything is run in the background so-to-speak to begin with. It's always difficult to answer questions not based on a real use case :)